# Cloud Functions for Firebase: how to get authenticated user in a database trigger

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firebase Cloud Function that listens to some db change, and goes like this:

```
exports.onCreateList = functions.database.ref('/lists/{list_id}').onCreate(event => {
```

How do I get the auth object (the details of the user who performed the operation)?

Comment: Can any user modify this Database node? or does it belong to only a specific user?

Comment: Any user can modify.